# Malsup's jQuery form plugins with file upload fail in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have used Malsup's jQuery form plugins for a quite some times. The plugins working great and the file upload is working using hidden iframe technique.

Yesterday I tried to use it in Google Chrome browser, but it failed. This morning I try the example in the http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload but I got the same failed result. Google chrome is displaying the iframe, instead of passing it to javascript.

I wonder if anyone have the same problems, hopefully have the workaround or fix for this. I also have tell Malsup about this via Twitter DM.

Thanks

Comment: While waiting for the possible answers, if you have similar problems, consider using a flash uploader, such as Uploadify and swfupload. I'm replacing the malsup's form plugins for form with file field with uploadify. The file will be uploaded using uploadify, then the form will be submitted in the uploadify onComplete handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the newer version of google chrome, and the latest version of [jQuery form plugins](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form), it's appear to working well.

Google Chrome version: 4.0.302.2 dev